# Dash multiple app server set Flask session

Tags: python-3.x, flask, plotly-dash, werkzeug

Let's say I have 2 apps running, and served by DispatcherMiddleware like the following:

**utils.py**

```
import uuid
from flask import session
def set_session():
    if 'uid ' not in session:
        uid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        session['uid'] = uid
```

**index.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**app1.py**

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import session
from utils import set_session

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    requests_pathname_prefix='/app1/'
)

def layout():
   set_session()
   return [html.Div('welcome', id='div'), html.Button(id='submit', n_clicks=0)]

app.layout = layout

@app.callback(Output('div', 'children'),
              [Input('submit', 'n_clicks')])
def print_session(n_clicks):
    return session['uid']
```

**app2.py**

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import session
from utils import set_session

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    requests_pathname_prefix='/app2/'
)

def layout():
   set_session()
   return [html.Div('welcome', id='div'), html.Button(id='submit', n_clicks=0)]

app.layout = layout

@app.callback(Output('div', 'children'),
              [Input('submit', 'n_clicks')])
def print_session(n_clicks):
    return session['uid']
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from index import app as index
from flask import Flask

from app1 import app as app1
from app2 import app as app2

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(index, {
    '/app1': app1.server,
    '/app2': app2.server,
})
```

I would like to have one session per user and per app.

But the above code raise the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\wsgi.py", line 24, in

> ```
> from app1 import app as app1
> ```

> File "C:\Users\app1.py", line 254, in

> ```
> app.layout = layout
> ```

> File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 510, in layout

> ```
> layout_value = self._layout_value()
> ```

> File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 476, in _layout_value

> ```
> return self._layout() if self._layout_is_function else self._layout
> ```

> File "C:\Users\app1.py", line 130, in layout

> ```
> if 'uid' not in session:
> ```

> File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 379, in

> ```
> __contains__ = lambda x, i: i in x._get_current_object()
> ```

> File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object

> ```
> return self.__local()
> ```

> File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object

> ```
> raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
> ```

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to store the session data (or just the session id) as part of your app layout. Here is a small example,

```
import uuid
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State


def layout():
    return html.Div([html.Div('Welcome', id='div'), html.Button("Submit", id='submit', n_clicks=0),
                     dcc.Store(id="session", data=dict(uid=str(uuid.uuid4())))])


app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = layout


@app.callback(Output('div', 'children'), [Input('submit', 'n_clicks')], State("session", "data"))
def print_session(_, session):
    return session['uid']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```